# How to zoom out Html element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to create cloud tags  in html.I am able to create them using ul tag  and applying css on them.Following is my cloud tag image:

[image]

Now i want effects like that, when i move my mouse to any of the text(i.e any cloud tag),say "Learn java" tag it should zoom out and when i move my mouse out of it it should go back to its place. I have seen this functionality on many websites.
following is my code in HTML file :

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#java").hover(function(){
    alert("You entered on java cloud tag!");
    },function); 
});
</script>
<title>Css Globe: tag clouds</title>
<style>

body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    background:#e1e1e1;
    font:80% Trebuchet MS, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color:#555;
    line-height:180%;
}
a{color:#3c70d0;}
h1{
    font-size:180%;
    font-weight:normal;
    margin:0 20px;
    padding:1em 0;
    }
h2{
    font-size:160%;
    font-weight:normal;
    }   
h3{
    font-size:140%;
    font-weight:normal;
    }   
img{border:none;}
pre{
    display:block;
    font:12px "Courier New", Courier, monospace;
    padding:10px;
    border:1px solid #bae2f0;
    background:#e3f4f9; 
    margin:.5em 0;
    width:500px;
    }   

#container{
    margin:0 auto;
    text-align:left;
    width:700px;
    background:#fff;
    }
#main{
    float:right;
    display:inline;
    width:380px;
    margin-left:20px;   
    }
#side{
    float:left;
    display:inline;
    width:260px;
    margin-left:20px;
    }   
#footer{
    clear:both;
    padding:1em 0;
    margin:0 20px;
    }


/* Tag cloud */

    .tags ul{
        margin:1em 0;
        padding:.5em 10px;
        text-align:center;
        background:#71b5e9 url(bg_tags.gif) repeat-x;       
        }

        .cld{
            height:100px;
            width:400px;
        }
    .tags li{
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
        list-style:none;
        display:inline;
        }
    .tags li a{
        text-decoration:none;
        color:#fff;
        padding:0 2px;  
        }
    .tags li a:hover{   
        color:#cff400;
        }       

    .tag1{font-size:100%;}
    .tag2{font-size:120%;}
    .tag3{font-size:140%;}
    .tag4{font-size:160%;}
    .tag5{font-size:180%;}

    /* alternative layout */

    .tags .alt{
        text-align:left;
        padding:0;
        background:none;
        }
    .tags .alt li{
        padding:2px 10px;
        background:#efefef;
        display:block;
        }
    .tags .alt .tag1, 
    .tags .alt .tag2, 
    .tags .alt .tag3, 
    .tags .alt .tag4, 
    .tags .alt .tag5{font-size:100%;}
    .tags .alt .tag1{background:#7cc0f4;}
    .tags .alt .tag2{background:#67abe0;}
    .tags .alt .tag3{background:#4d92c7;}
    .tags .alt .tag4{background:#3277ad;}
    .tags .alt .tag5{background:#266ca2;}

/* // Tag cloud */

</style>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

</script>

</head>

<body>  <!--******************************************************************************-->>

<div id="container">    




    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cssglobe.com/ads/blogsponsor.js"></script>



    <div id="side">

        <h2>Side column (Tag Cloud)</h2>

        <div class="tags">
            <ul class="cld">
                <li class="tag1" id="java"><a href="https://www.google.com">Learn java</a></li> 
                <li class="tag2"><a href="#">Find Markets</a></li>
                <li class="tag3"><a href="#">sitemap</a></li>
                <li class="tag2"><a href="#">Sales</a></li>
                <li class="tag4"><a href="#">Gohome</a></li>
                <li class="tag1"><a href="#">Movies</a></li>
                <li class="tag1"><a href="#">It Jobz</a></li>
                <li class="tag5"><a href="#">Gym</a></li>
                <li class="tag2"><a href="#">Sea food</a></li>
                <li class="tag1"><a href="#">Hospital</a></li>
                <li class="tag3"><a href="#">Smart phone</a></li>
                <li class="tag4"><a href="#">Pizza </a></li>
                <li class="tag1"><a href="#">Aerobics</a></li>
                <li class="tag5"><a href="#">Electronics</a></li>
                <li class="tag1"><a href="#">Anti-Virus</a></li>
                <li class="tag2"><a href="#">Travel</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>



</div>

</body>
</html>
```

,So please give some solution to achive this.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: You can use CSS3 Transitions and just increase the size of the text. Google css transition and transform

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*This is what you want.* - [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zC2rx/)

**Add to CSS:**

```
.tags ul li {
    -moz-transition: font-size 0.2s;
    -webkit-transition: font-size 0.2s;
    transition: font-size 0.2s;
}
```

**Replace jQuery with:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#java").hover(function(){
      $(this).css({'fontSize': '150%'});
  }, function(){
      $(this).css({'fontSize': '100%'}); 
  });
});
```

Adjust sizes/timings/etc as appropriate.

Cheers.

Answer (score 3):

just use css3 transform scale property

```
.element{
  -webkit-transform:scale3d(1,1,1);
  -moz-transform:scale3d(1,1,1);
  -transform:scale3d(1,1,1);
  -webkit-transition:300ms ease-in-out all;
  -moz-transition:300ms ease-in-out all;
  transition:300ms ease-in-out all;
}

.element:hover{
  -webkit-transform:scale3d(1.4,1.4,1.4);
  -moz-transform:scale3d(1.4,1.4,1.4);
  transform:scale3d(1.4,1.4,1.4);
}
```

demo:http://jsfiddle.net/raJwX/

**

1. Update:

**

Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/raJwX/1/

```
    .tags li {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-block;
    -webkit-transform:scale3d(1,1,1);
    -moz-transform:scale3d(1,1,1);
    -transform:scale3d(1,1,1);
    -webkit-transition:300ms ease-in-out all;
    -moz-transition:300ms ease-in-out all;
    transition:300ms ease-in-out all;
    }
    .tags li a{
        text-decoration:none;
        color:#fff;
        padding:0 2px;  
        }
    .tags li:hover{   
        -webkit-transform:scale3d(1.4,1.4,1.4);
        -moz-transform:scale3d(1.4,1.4,1.4);
        transform:scale3d(1.4,1.4,1.4);
        }
```

Comment: Yes its zooming out but transition effects are not showing smoothly(as showing on "http://jsfiddle.net/raJwX/").it directly encrise size and goes back when mouse is moved out. So please can u suggest me a solution

Comment: @user2681213 then change  display: inline; to display: inline-block; as you can see on update

Answer (score 1):

CSS **"transform"** property is what you are looking for that this will help you out to achieve this.

However I just took your code and made changes in two CSS classes

```
 .tags li a{
        text-decoration:none;
        display:inline-block;
        -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
        color:#fff;
        padding:0 2px;  
        }
    .tags li a:hover{   
        color:#cff400;
        -webkit-transform: scale(1.3);
        }
```

For reference http://jsfiddle.net/yNt6X/3/

Hope you gets what you are looking for.

P.S. I have just added css for webkit browser.

Comment: This will only help him in chrome and safari

Comment: yep that's right, but he gets the idea. i did specify in Post script.

Comment: Yeah sorry I noticed that after sending

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery `.css()` property you can change font size to smaller which make an effect of "zoom out" but actually the font is only smaller.

**Example**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#java").hover(function(){
    $("#java").css('font-size', "10px");
  }); 
});
</script>
```

Also, when you out of hovering "Learn Java" you can use the event `onMouseOut` to return the font to his normal font size.

**Example**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#java").mouseout(function(){
    $("#java").css('font-size', "18px"); // Assuming that normal font is 18px.
  }); 
});
</script>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dXakP/)

Answer (score 0):

Animate method can be used with best effect as used in following link

```
  $(this).animate({width: "500px"}, 'slow');
```

Above method is called on mouseover and mouseout function on html element.

http://jsfiddle.net/jquerybyexample/nPeaV/